# Editing the size of rectangular grid tool in Adobe Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've been painting a pixel character in a of 32x32, but after the work is almost done I noticed I needed a little more dots, Is there any way to edit the grid to something like 64x64?

If not, is there any way to copy the painted dots inside a bigger grid and paste in another rectangular grid?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new grid by selecting the Rectangular Grid Tool (a subset of the Line Segment Tool) and then clicking anywhere within the artboard. If you want to over lay this in the same spot as your prior grid you will click on the top left point. This will prompt you with a Rectangular Grid Tool Options tool box. you can then change the settings to be 64px x 64px or however large you choose.

[image: Rectangular Grid Tool button location]

[image: Grid Settings]

After you've created the new grid you can make a duplicate of your original work and paste it on the new grid. To ensure pixel perfect accuracy you should consider having  **View → Snap To Point** checked.

Comment: This change the whole Artboard. What I meant was the Rectangular Grid Tool.

Comment: @Iserafim I've changed my answer per your comment

Comment: Heres a example:

http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/4810/a4se.jpg

I want to transfer, for instance, the image 1, into the new grid, or make the grid of the first image bigger.

Comment: So you are asking how to copy paste that boxed 1 into the new grid?

Comment: yeah, thats it, copy the boxed 1 in the new grid

Comment: Select it, group it, copy and paste it, adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon comments to Adams answer....

There's no feasible reason to use the grid tool to create an actual grid object.

Simply choose `View > Show Grid`. And to edit it, choose `Preferences > Guides & Grid`.

If you are using the grid as a guide, then use the built in feature for this, not the Rectangular Grid Tool.

Comment: A reason is I want a grid in my design.

Answer (score 0):

Edit> Preferences> Guides & Grid>
Then change the gridline frequency to whatever size you want